# Array has duplicate values with different id, how to remove duplicates

Tags: php, arrays, csv

My array is like this:

```
Array (
  [0] => Array (
    [0] => aaa-aaa
    [SKU] => aaa-aaa
    [1] => 12/1/1
    [date] => 12/1/1
    [2] => 1.15
    [cost] => 1.15 )
  [1] => Array (
    [0] => bbb-bbb
    [SKU] => bbb-bbb
    [1] => 10/1/1
    [date] => 10/1/1
    [2] => 0.15
    [cost] => 0.15 )
)
```

I'd like to merge the matching values to each other, or make a new array selecting the indexes, or use a php tool to print specified indexes to csv: aaa-aaa, 12/1/1, 1.15 \n bbb-bbb, 10/1/1, 0.15

It cannot be queried because this information is coming from 4 different tables, from 2 different sql providers. These arrays are the result of mapping previous arrays.

`array_unique()` doesn't work, `array_diff()` doesn't work, `array_diff_key()` doesn't work.

You direction is much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried anything

Comment: Tell your database query to return either enumerated or associative but not the default both

Comment: so many duplicates, it would of taken you less time to search than ask

Comment: Listen to @MarkBaker... fetch_assoc

Comment: What @MarkBaker said ...

Comment: @AbraCadaver He doesn't say that he's using a Database. Maybe this is the return of an API request..?

Comment: @BennetG. Possible but not probable ;-)

Comment: @BennetG. - But experience says it's most likely to be the database default fetch

Comment: Question updated. The above array is the result of 5 database queries, from 4 tables, from 2 sql providers. The results of those queries were mapped because of additional filtering requested by client.

Comment: So change the fetch parameter or function that fetches those arrays before mapping.

Comment: @AbraCadaver, to do so would mess up the results of the queries. I cannot alter the functions without rewriting the entire script.

Comment: So you want to fetch duplicate data on purpose and modify it and then remove duplicates? The duplicates don't come from the query but from the fetch function.

Comment: Changing whether you fetch enumerated, associative or both shouldn't change the actual queries themselves at all, just the keys of the array that's fetched

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```
$result = array_unique($input);
print_r($result);
```

If you want keep only string keys:

```
 $result = array();
foreach ($array as $key => $value){
  if(!is_numeric($key)
     $result[$key]=$value;
  }
```

In your case the array size should always be even and  has no gaps between indexes so you can do something like:

```
$length = count($array)/2;
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
  unset($array[i]);
}
```

You can also do:

```
 $dummy = array_fill(0, count($input), 'banana');
 $result = array_diff_key($input, $dummy);
```

Comment: You'll lose all of the string keys and if you have any other duplicate data other than the matching pair you will lose that as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answers but they did not work for me. array_reduce() worked.